# Marking ToString virtual in base class, what happens?

Tags: c#, virtual, overriding

Consider the following (LinqPad) example. ToString in class X is marked virtual. Why is the output here not equal to "Hi, I'm Y, Hi, I'm X" but instead the typename is printed? Of course marking ToString virtual is wrong, because it is defined in Object as virtual, I am just trying to understand what is happening here.

```
void Main()
{
    Y y = new Y();
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

class X
{
  public virtual String ToString() 
  {
    return "Hi, I'm X";
  }
}

class Y : X
{
  public override String ToString() 
  {
    return "Hi, I'm Y, " + base.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Here is a great demo on virtual and non-virtual methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's creating a *new* virtual method in `X` called `ToString()` which hides `Object.ToString()`. So if you have:

```
Y y = new Y();
X x = y;
Object o = y;

Console.WriteLine(y.ToString()); // Shows "Hi, I'm Y, Hi, I'm X";
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); // Shows "Hi, I'm Y, Hi, I'm X";
Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()); // Calls object.ToString; shows just "Y"
```

Calling just

```
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

is equivalent to the final line, which is why the type name is printed.

Basically, your `X.ToString` method should *override* the `object.ToString()` method:

```
public override String ToString() 
{
    return "Hi, I'm X";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

By using `virtual String ToString()` on `class X`, you're "hiding" `object.ToString` instead of overriding it.

When you call `Console.WriteLine(y);`, it calls `object.ToString()`.  Since you didn't override this, your method never gets called.

That being said, the compiler will warn you:

> Warning   1   'X.ToString()' hides inherited member 'object.ToString()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword.

Comment: No warnings in LinqPad... wish they were there ;).

Comment: Try the latest LINQPad beta (www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) - it should now displays warnings.