# How can I see warnings in Linqpad?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-warnings, linqpad

When I create C# Programs in LinqPad, I would like to see the warnings from the compiler. It already shows error messages. How can I see the warnings?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's supported.

Comment: This feature has been suggested on UserVoice: http://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/704610-show-compiler-warnings?ref=title

Comment: @Thomas Levesque:+1 thanx for link.. we'll keep an eye on it.. however i think this not a feature expected from a scratch pad.. will hamper its performance if they keep adding IDE like features.. infact that's why i prefer opening LINQPAD instead of VS

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949025/marking-tostring-virtual-in-base-class-what-happens/4949061#4949061 which was the reason why I asked. I like firing up Linqpad for such small examples as well, still warnings would be nice and not really performance critical.

Comment: The latest beta (www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) now displays warnings - let me know how you get along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQPAD is not a full blown IDE to support everything.. it's an ergonomic C#/VB scratchpad that instantly executes any C#/VB expression, statement block or program..

so simply this feature is not supported as of now.