# In LinqPad: "Query completed successfully with warnings"

Tags: linqpad

When running (a pretty experimental) linq query I get: "Query completed successfully with warnings" in the toolbar, how do I find the warnings? As they don't appear in the dump window.

n.b. At the time of writing I'm using linqpad v4.47.02 premium edition.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951069/how-can-i-see-warnings-in-linqpad (although that question is quite old)

Comment: Do you not get a little yellow warning triangle at the start of the line containing the warning?

Comment: Interesting my searches didn't come up with the duplicate. But you're right it's very old and Joe mentions a beta that should support it.

Comment: No yellow triangle I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm using the same version as you and http://imgur.com/83JKN9Y is a screenshot of what I get. And if you hover over the warning it tells you what the warning is.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, but it doesn't seem to be loading, it says file not found.

Comment: Dude, I can't believe I missed that. My query is so long I didn't see those triangles. If you stick it in as an answer I'll give you some magic points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should get a little yellow warning triangle at the start of the line(s) that contains the warning.

And when you hover over the triangle, it show display what the actual warning is.

See screenshot

[image: Example Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

As of V5.36.03 Premium I see the triangle, then I don't.

In short the triangle disappears the second time you execute a query if no code changes are made.

I have reported a bug through LinqPad:

Yellow warning triangle disappears, when [F5] is hit twice in a row with no source code changes.

The status bar continues to show Query completed successfully with warnings.

After a change is made, the triangle reappears for the next run only.

Sample code is trivial:

```
void Main()
{
    var v = 1;
}
```

Problem was found in a longer useful query.